# How to use event from child to parent

Tags: angular, typescript, events

I want to share `totalJobsLength` from child to parent. I get `totalJobsLength` from `ChildComponent.component.ts` on this function:

```
this.search.setup({
  .....
     };
     return this.service
       .searchJobs(projectid, payload)
       .pipe(
         tap(
           (page) =>
           (this.totalJobsLength = page.totalElements
           )
         ),
         map((page) => ({
 ....
         }))
       );
   }
 });
```

So my components hierarchy is:

```
ParentsComponent
--ChildComponent
       >ChildComponent.component.ts
       >ChildComponent.component.html
>ParentsComponent.component.ts
>ParentsComponent.component.html
```

I want to show `totalJobsLength` on `ParentsComponent.component.html`

```
 <p-tabPanel [header]="'All'">   //here I want to show `totalJobsLength`
        <ldd-child></ldd-child>
    </p-tabPanel>
```

Please can you share any idea how to implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Child Component .ts

```
@Output totalJobsLengthEvent = new EventEmitter<number>();

...........

this.search.setup({
  .....
     };
     return this.service
       .searchJobs(projectid, payload)
       .pipe(
         tap(
           (page) =>
           (this.totalJobsLength = page.totalElements;
            this.totalJobsLengthEvent.emit(page.totalElements);
           )
         ),
         map((page) => ({
 ....
         }))
       );
   }
 });
```

Parent Component .ts

```
onTotalJobsLength(value) =>{
  console.log('Total Jobs Length', value);
  this.totalJobsLengthParent= value;
}
```

Parent Component .html

```
<h1>Total Jobs Length - {{totalJobsLengthParent}} </h1>
 <p-tabPanel [header]="'All'">   //here I want to show `totalJobsLength`
        <ldd-child (totalJobsLengthEvent) = "onTotalJobsLength($event)"></ldd-child>
 </p-tabPanel>
```

Comment: Thank you! Works good, only  in this part `(this.totalJobsLength = page.totalElements;
            this.totalJobsLengthEvent.emit(page.totalElements);
           )` we don't use `;` but `,`